# Express: MySQL query doesn't push code to a list

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I have been trying to push the results of MySQL query to a list(shoppingList), but the shoppingList is always empty, even though I'm getting 2 results back.

I think the problem is somewhere with handling the promise, but I haven't been able to figure it out:

```
static async showShoppingList(userId) {
    let shoppingList = [];
    const sql =
      "SELECT item_name, family_member_name FROM shopping_list WHERE user_id = (?)";
    await db.promise().query(sql, [userId], function (err, results) {
      for (const result of results) {
        shoppingList.push(result)
        console.log(shoppingList) // Here it appears with results
      }
    });
    console.log(shoppingList) // Here it appears empty
    return shoppingList;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the callback `function(err, results)` is executed *asynchronously*, after the database has returned the results, whereas the other statement is executed *synchronously*:

1. `db.promise().query` sends the query to the database.
2. The empty `shoppingList` is written to the console and returned.
3. After the database has returned the `results`, the callback function is executed, writing the full `shoppingList` to the console.